# first request to ActiveRecord boolean field with false value gives true in rails 3

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, actionview

I have such code in my view:

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
<tr<%= raw(item.presence ? '' : ' class="opaque"') %>>
...
<td><%= item.presence ? 'Yes' : 'No' %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

this is request in controller:

```
@items = Item.where(:type_id => @type.id).order('brand ASC, name ASC').limit(limit).offset((@page-1)*limit)
```

'presence' field is just bool, nil in first item
Despite the fact that the first acquired item's presence field is nil, it doesn't return class attr for the first row (like it is not nil or true), but the second check returns right value ('No'). In the other rows with false or nil values it returns right values in both checks. Is it a bug, or I'm doing smth wrong?

Rails 3.0.0, Postgres 8.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does adding the ? to presence  help...

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
<tr<%= raw(item.presence? ? '' : ' class="opaque"') %>>
...
<td><%= item.presence? ? 'Yes' : 'No' %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. That really helped. But I am still discouraged of this strange behavior, that the same field method first time gives wrong value, and right value in the rest.

Comment: even with the ?  forcing AR to treat the value as boolean, you are still no  getting class="opauqe" in the first call?

Comment: sorry, I incorrectly exressed myself. ? method from your answer works right all times. I don't understand behavior of method without ?.

Comment: I am not sure either. Without the ? AR is just passing the value of the field up, and then the ternary if is what is forcing it to the boolean. With the ? AR is doing the conversion to boolean (since Different DBs have Differen ways of representing true false (ie tinyint(0) or tinyint(1). 't' || 'f' etc.. )  Did you look at the raw row from the DB or just echo out item.presence to see exactly what AR was working with.

Comment: Actualy in DB this field is NULL, and item.presence.inspect gives nil

Comment: I suspect it's a pq gem issue, and solved it by forcing FALSE value to DB instead of NULL, though it's not convenient, because checkbox is used for this field in editing form.

Comment: Don't think its to do with null, I hit this problem and the field has a default of true...